# rails iterating thru js.erb collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I do infinite pagination with AJAX call + index.js.erb. When I render the new posts I'd like to call a js function on them. With the following code it renders the new posts, but doesn't call the `showPostEditDropdown` function on them.

How can I iterate thru the freshly inserted posts to call the function on them?

The `showPostEditDropdown` function is working well since from the `update.js.erb` file I can invoke it properly on a single post instance.

index.js.erb

```
$posts = '<%= j render @posts %>'
$('.new-post-insert').append($posts);
//the following is not working at the moment
$posts.each(function(index) {
  showPostEditDropdown($(this));
});
```

posts.js

```
function showPostEditDropdown($container) {
  if ($container.find('.edit-post-dropdown-button').data('postauthorid') == $('#bodycurrentuser').data('currentuserid')) {
    $container.find('.edit-post-dropdown-button').removeClass('hidden');
  };
};
```

Comment: Any error message on this?

Comment: No error message, but the code after the each function (I don't show that here) doesn't run. The cod before the each function (rendering) works fine.

Comment: Yeah that means there may be an issue at `each`, did you check the type of `$posts`, I think it is the clue to fix this!

Comment: Hieu, I'm pretty bad at jQuery, how can I do that?

Comment: Put these commands before `$post.each`: debugger; var isArray = $.isArray($posts);  Run it then check your browser console to see what happens

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109837/discussion-between-hieu-pham-and-szilard-magyar).